# Auto case-sensitive find and replace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I'm attempting to create a macro in Google Sheets that will automatically perform case sensitive find and replace across specific sheet tabs. There is a specific string I need to search for and replace.

This is the code I have so far. I can tell it's missing some crucial features but I'm not sure what they are. Can anyone help me to finish it?

```
function UntitledMacro() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A:G').activate();
var to_replace = "/creditcards/low-interest-credit-cards";
var replace_with = "/";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),7);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var search="/creditcards/low-interest-credit-cards";
  var pattern=new RegExp(search,"g");
  var replacement="/";
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=0;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(vA[i][j].toString().indexOf(search)>-1) {
        vA[i][j]=vA[i][j].toString().replace(pattern,replacement);
      }
    }
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it works perfectly. The only issue now is that I want to be able to set it to run automatically and as my sheet has multiple tabs I need to be able to tell it to set active sheet. Usually I do this with the following code at the start of the macro:

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var firstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[2];
var secondSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[3];
var thirdSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[4];
var fourthSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[5];
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(firstSheet);

But that's not working here?

Comment: I don't see the value in setting the active sheet since you can't see anything changing while the script is running.  In my world I would just use getSheetByName() and run through the sheets all at one time.  With this in mind you could perform this operation without even having the sheet open by any user.  But it's your project do it the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can record a macro using Find and Replace User interface and ticking off "Match case". Your macro will then contain

```
.matchCase(true)
```

#### Ref:

- [TextFinder#matchCase](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchCase(Boolean))